# Does my Git Bash (for Windows) username have to be the same as my remote repository in GitHub?

Tags: git, git-bash

Can anyone please let me know if my `Git Bash (For Windows)`username` has to be the same as my remote repository in GitHub?

Comment: I’m not entirely sure what you are asking, but in general no: The Windows username, your GitHub username, the author name configured in Git, and everything else you could think of can be completely different. As long as the remote URL to your GitHub repository is correct, you will be able to interact with your remote repository using your GitHub credentials.

Answer (score 3):

NO,

You can set **any** username and email you want locally.
You can even set any email you desire using the `-c` flag per commit (override the default config values).

```
# set any desired commit user name email
git commit -c user.email "a@aa.net" -c user.name "aaaa"
```

The user name /email you set locally are only used for your commit metadata and has nothing to do with your github account.

---

```
git -c user.name="Darth Vader" -c user.email="star@wars.com" commit -m "Message"
```

Now the data in the commit will be the following:

[image]

Comment: Nor does it have anything to do with the repository name.